# How does core-selector's 'core-select' event work?

Tags: polymer

I notice some strangeness in how `core-selector`'s `core-select` event is fired.

Let's say we have :

HTML:

```
<core-selector multi>
  <div>item 1</div>
  <div>item 2</div>
  <div>item 3</div>
</core-selector>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector('core-selector').addEventListener('core-select', function (event) {
  console.log(event.detail.item.textContent);
  console.log(event.detail.isSelected);
});
```

I find that when I select `item 1` followed by `item 2` I see that for the last selection, the event is fired multiple times. It gets fired 3 times:

1. Unselection of item 1
2. Selection of item 1
3. Selection of item 2

Is this supposed to be happening?

I expected the event to be fired once for every selection/unselection with event.detail.item being the item that was clicked on.

Also, is there a way to get a remote version of core-selector.html that I can use on JSBin to show you a demo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a known behavior: https://github.com/Polymer/paper-tabs/issues/26

> "This is expected. core-selector's core-select event is fired when an
>   item's selection state is changed. This event is fired both when an
>   item is selected or deselected. So that's why you see 2 events for a
>   single tap, one for selected and one for deselected.
>
> You can use isSelected from the event.detail to check the selection
>   state." **- frankiefu commented on Sep 23, 2014**

```
    var tabs = document.querySelector('#tabs');
tabs.addEventListener('core-select', function(e) {
  if (e.detail.isSelected) {
    console.log("Selected: " + tabs.selected);
  }
});
```

However, Rob Dodson on the Polymer team had something else to add:

> > I'd like to revisit this issue if possible because I keep getting bug reports about it: Polymer/docs#696
>
> Also, from one of the DAs running through the tutorial:
>
> The double firing of events seems really weird - yes there is multiple
>   selections from core-selector (according to the note) but I’m
>   selecting one tab - this definitely feels like a bug and not sane. And
>   I personally agree, it just feels odd when I select one tab to get 2
>   events that I have to dig through to figure out who was clicked.

So who knows

Answer (score 0):

The `core` and `paper` elements are hosted at `//www.polymer-project.org/components/` so you can make JsBins like so:

http://jsbin.com/geseni/3/edit

The effect you are seeing is caused by the way `core-selector` implements multi-select. I believe this is improper and we've just missed it because we tend to use binding over events.

I've posted an issue ticket: https://github.com/Polymer/core-selector/issues/6

Answer (score 0):

Use **core-activate** instead of **core-selected** to handle single select events. Use core-selected for event history.